# Does Monero still use the Cryptonight algorithm since the fork?

Tags: hashrate, cryptonight, algorithm, difficulty-algorithm

Ok, I have read about the Lithium Luna release that's supposed to be ASIC resistant.  However, I'm unclear about whether Monero is now using a new hash algorithm.  Is Monero still using its CryptoNight algorithm or some variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, it is still using the Cryptonight design, but the v7 hardfork included some modifications to the algorithm to brick the current generation of ASICs.

See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3253/files

All v6 mining software, including pools, have had to upgrade to match the new algorithm.

Comment: [Overview of "some modification"](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/7943/2604)

Comment: You can see the full PR here https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3253