# What's the scratchpad for?

Tags: algorithm, monero-network-hashrate, hash-verification, difficulty-algorithm

Attempting to follow the pseudo-code here -- [What exactly has been changed in PoW algorithms in the v7 fork?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/what-exactly-has-been-changed-in-pow-algorithms-in-the-v7-fork/7943#7943), I was curious about this part of the Monero hashing algorithm ...

```
scratchpad = fill_scratchpad(state)
```

What is the scratchpad for?  When you "fill" the scratchpad, are you simply taking the value (state) from teh step above and prepending zeroes to it until you have 2 MB worth of data?

Answer (score 2):

The scratchpad is filled with pseudo-random data based on the state (using rounds of the AES block cipher).

Check https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt for a detailed description of the algorithm (without the modifications introduced in version 7 of the protocol).

Comment: Omg this is incredibly complex for my primitive mind.  Are there any examples that work through the hash process with specific numbers?

Comment: Not that know of.