# Cannot build OpenCL program for GPU 0

Tags: mining

Everything i try to mine with Claymore I get these errors and hashrate is 0. Have tryed also zcash and ethereum.

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║         Claymore's CryptoNote AMD GPU Miner v10.2 Beta         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Wrong Monero wallet address, "-allpools 1" option will be enabled automatically, read Readme for details.
XMR: 6 pools are specified
Main Monero pool is xmr-eu1.nanopool.org:14433
At least 16 GB of Virtual Memory is required for multi-GPU systems
Make sure you defined GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
Be careful with overclocking, use default clocks for first tests
Press "s" for current statistics, "0".."9" to turn on/off cards, "r" to reload pools
OpenCL initializing...
AMD Cards available: 2
GPU #0: gfx900, 8176 MB available, 56 compute units
GPU #0 recognized as Vega
GPU #1: gfx900, 8176 MB available, 56 compute units
GPU #1 recognized as Vega
POOL version
Cannot build OpenCL program for GPU 0
Cannot build OpenCL program for GPU 1
GPU #0 algorithm ASM, -h 2000, -dmem 0 (Memory used: 4200MB)
GPU #1 algorithm ASM, -h 2000, -dmem 0 (Memory used: 4200MB)
Total cards: 2
"-allpools" option is set, default pools can be used for devfee, check "Readme" file for details.
Watchdog enabled
Remote management (READ-ONLY MODE) is enabled on port 3333
XMR: Stratum - connecting to 'xmr-eu1.nanopool.org' <213.32.29.143> port 14433 (SSL/TLS)

SSL/TLS encryption is enabled
XMR: Stratum - Connected (xmr-eu1.nanopool.org:14433) (SSL/TLS)
XMR: 06/08/18-21:12:39 - New job from xmr-eu1.nanopool.org:14433
XMR - Total Speed: 0 H/s, Total Shares: 0, Rejected: 0, Time: 00:00
XMR: GPU0 0 H/s, GPU1 0 H/s
GPU0 t=32C fan=12%, GPU1 t=40C fan=12%
```

Comment: Can it be due Hardfork of Monero?  - more details on https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/what-exactly-has-been-changed-in-pow-algorithms-in-the-v7-fork. Try latest sgminer https://github.com/genesismining/sgminer-gm they did update.